# Rooks in 3D chess board

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

How many rooks are needed for a 3D chess board of size NxNxN so that every empty cube on the board can be reached by a rook in a single move?

Comment: Naive bounds: $\frac{N^3}{3N-2}\leq f(N)\leq N^2$, where the lower bound comes from a situation where no two rooks cover the same square, and the upper bound comes from if every square on the base had a rook.

Comment: Experimentally, $f(2)=2$ and $f(3)=5$.

Comment: $(n-1)^2+1$ ? By induction ?

Comment: The best I've been able to do with an induction approach was to reprove the upper bound of $N^2$ in the asymptotic form - I got $f(N)=f(N-1)+2N-1$.

Comment: One each along the (long) diagonal of the cube?

Comment: That reminds me of Big Bang Theory.

Comment: @vonbrand That strategy doesn't cover every subcube. Consider a $3\times 3\times 3$ cube. Then placing rooks at $(1,1,1)$, $(2,2,2)$, $(3,3,3)$ doesn't cover the subcube at $(1,2,3)$.

Comment: I found $$f(n)\geq\begin{cases}
\frac{n^{2}}{2} & n\textrm{ even}\\
\\
\frac{n^{2}+1}{2} & n\textrm{ odd}
\end{cases}
 $$ and I'm pretty sure this is also a lower bound but I can't prove it.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000982

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also seen this as the 'broken combination lock' problem, and found that a simple 'cube' visualization helped to show how the minimum number of rooks actually looks.
See http://iantotman.blogspot.ca/2014/09/the-broken-combination-lock-problem.html

Comment: Can you describe the contents of that link, at least briefly? Your answer should remain valid even if the link dies at some point.

Comment: Sure...the gist is that you can think of this as an 8x8x8 cube. Each guess at a location (or a combination in the 'broken combination lock problem) 'cuts out' a line of 1 x 1 x 1 cubes in each of the 'x', 'y' and 'z' directions from the specific (x, y, z) cube selected. If you select say (1,1,1) - then you are selecting all cubes that have the same x,y but a different z, all cubes that have the same x,z but different y and all cubes that have the same y,z but different x (shown in the diagram). Together, these make a '3-dimensional L' shape. From some symmetry considerations you can show:

Comment: That the solution is (n^2)/2 (n=even) or (n^2+1)/2 (n=odd). Then some specific solutions are shown to show the approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is equivalent to finding the maximum number of rooks to place in a 3D chessboard such that none of them are non-attacking. This is because having the maximum number of rooks such that they are non attacking means that any other rook placed will result in at least a pair of rooks attacking each other. Thus, this also mean that the maximum number of rooks such that none are non-attacking is the minimum number of rooks that is needed such that all cubes can be reached in a single move.

And the answer hence is N^2. (Reference to a paper by Arthur low, Shalin Mehta. Rook Polynomial in 3D)

Comment: The questions are not equivalent, and I should correct my last comment, which should read $f(n)\leq\left\lceil \frac{n^{2}}{2}\right\rceil$ and I believe this is also an upper bound.

An answer to my problem in 3x3x3 is (0,0,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(2,2,2). An answer to yours is (0,0,0),(0,1,1),(0,2,2),(1,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,2,1),(2,0,1),(2,1,2),(2,0,2).

Comment: Its not N^2. That's just an upper bound